# Alchemy | Extend the Publishing Dialog GUI to include some info to the publish instructions

Tags: web8, gui-extensions, sdl-tridion, a4t

Raising this question to have a discussion to see how Alchemy can do the tricks here.

**Question is:**

How alchemy can be useful in writing to Page object while publishing? may be during rendering..!

**Or**

How can you extend the Publishing Dialog GUI to include an option to choose to include some additional info to the publish instructions using Alchemy

Ex: suppose I want to write a metadata to a page based on TargetTypes?

Comment: Thanks Nuno, honestly what you said is absolutely right. I did have this point before asking this question. To clear that I had a quick chat with Saurabh Gangwar (I had seen he demod something like that in summit) .. and in his opinion this seems possible.. (possible?). We agreed to dragged this topic here so that we can have little bit of discussion on this.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll delete my comments so it doesn't derail others from answering